# OR condition in xsl template match xpath is not working

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xslt-1.0

I am trying to write a xsl which will return xpaths of element and its immediate children

Sample XML

```
<level0>
    <level1>
        <level2>
            <level3>
                <level4/>
            </level3>
            <level3/>
        </level2>
    </level1>
</level0>
```

For example, if I want to return the xpaths of `level2` then it should return

```
/level0/level1/level2
/level0/level1/level2/level3
/level0/level1/level2/level3
```

My XSL

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
     <xsl:output method="text" media-type="text/plain"/>
    <xsl:template match="@*|comment()|text()|processing-instruction()"/>
     <xsl:template match="//level2|//level2/*">
        <xsl:for-each select="ancestor-or-self::*">
            <xsl:value-of select="concat('/',name(.))"/>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

In this xsl, I am trying to match the template for `//level2|//level2/*` xpath (which should return the desired result). However, I am only getting

```
/level0/level1/level2
```

How do I get the desired result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add `<xsl:apply-templates/>` after `<xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>`

```
<xsl:template match="//level2|//level2/*">
    <xsl:for-each select="ancestor-or-self::*">
        <xsl:value-of select="concat('/',name(.))"/>
    </xsl:for-each>
    <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>
```

**Output**

```
/level0/level1/level2
/level0/level1/level2/level3
/level0/level1/level2/level3
```